# Routing within a Bootstrap Modal Window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and i'm using bootstrap for modal window. I have certain queries on how to implement it properly.

1) Should a Modal Window be a route?

In the example the window is triggered by a javascript rather than a route on an anchor

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IDOoeYQticjRZA4uMGJx?p=preview

Is the above approach correct or should there be a route to trigger? If yes then how can I do it, example would be much appreciated.

2) If javascript is used to trigger the window how can I do routing inside the modal window?

PS : I did watch http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router video on the ui-router for understanding but not sure how it can be implemented when javascript is used.

I did try triggering the modal from a link but it does not open up the second time.
http://plnkr.co/edit/b2Hy7VIjgBwI8HpI90KN?p=preview

Example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I use Foundation's reveal with AngularJS, which is similar to Bootstap's modal.  The modal itself isn't a separate route, as like you, I trigger it via Javascript from the controller.  I think this is fine though, as it's usually related to the scope of that controller, e.g. creating / editing records for the list, etc.

The content of the modal/reveal is a separate template though, so is only loaded and cached as needed, and the modal has its own controller.  My 'parent' controller can inject values into the reveal controller via the provider I use, which is presumably similar to how the Bootstrap modal provider works.

So, in my opinion I think it's perfectly valid for the modal to not have its own route, but perhaps someone out there has implemented things differently.

Update: I also think that routing (with the ng-view directive) is more about single page applications.  As the ng-view element is constant, I don't quite see how that would work with modals, as you'd presumably lose the context of the view from which it is loaded.